# Cannot construct data type datetime, some of the arguments have values which are not valid

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I get this error on following code; 
Msg 289, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
Cannot construct data type datetime, some of the arguments have values which are not valid.

But i think values are valid.

```
MERGE INTO tblAveraj WITH (HOLDLOCK) 
USING tblDegerSon ON 
  (tblAveraj.AdresID = tblDegerSon.AdresID 
    AND tblAveraj.Baslangic = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2014, 11, 11, 11, 0, 0, 0))
WHEN MATCHED 
     THEN 
         UPDATE 
            SET tblAveraj.Toplam = tblAveraj.Toplam + tblDegerSon.Deger, 
                tblAveraj.Sure = tblAveraj.Sure + 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
     THEN 
         INSERT (AdresID, Baslangic, Bitis, Toplam, Sure) 
         VALUES (
                   tblDegerSon.AdresID, 
                   DATETIMEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()), 
                                      DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()), 
                                      DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()), 
                                      DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()), 0, 0, 0), 
                   DATETIMEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()), 
                                     DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()), 
                                     DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()), 
                                     DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) + 1, 0, 0, 0), 
                   Deger, 1);
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75415253/cannot-construct-data-type-datetime-when-filtering-data-but-all-values-filter?noredirect=1&lq=1, where this can happen even if the values that it *should* be called on are all valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the only reason I can see is that the very last DATETIMEFROMPARTS in the INSERT part for the column `Bitis` (if I read it correctly):

```
DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) + 1
```

overflows when the hour + 1 gets above 24.

Doing:

```
SELECT DATETIMEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()), DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()), DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()), DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) + 2, 0, 0, 0)
```

right now (my local time is `2014-11-23 22:53:49.383`) gives me the same error.

The quick fix would be to do a `case when DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE())+1 > 24 then 0 end` or something similar.

Answer (score 4):

These type of error while using `DATETIMEFROMPARTS`

If I passed an invalid argument to `DATETIMEFROMPARTS` ex(day cannot be 32 in a month & hour cannot be 25 in a day) to above functions. So the constructor of this function cannot create a date from these arguments, so it generates the error.

Whenever you come across this error, please check the arguments passed in the function. The arguments must be valid to avoid this error.

The short and sweet summary is that the `DATETIMEFROMPARTS` **function takes valid integers as input for year, month,date and hour**. It returns a date variable representing the parts. Any NULL input values result in NULL output values. Last but not least, any invalid input results in a ERROR.