# "Cannot construct data type datetime" when filtering data, but all values filtered DO have valid dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

*I am convinced that this question is NOT a duplicate of:
[Cannot construct data type datetime, some of the arguments have values which are not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094715/cannot-construct-data-type-datetime-some-of-the-arguments-have-values-which-are)*

*In that case the values passed in are explicitly not valid. Whereas in this case the values that the function could be expected to be called upon **are** all valid.*

*I know what the actual problem is, and it's not something that would help most people that find the other question. But it IS something that would be good to be findable on SO.*

*Please read the answer, and understand why it's different from the linked question before voting to close as dupe of that question.*

---

I've run some SQL that's errored with the error message: `Cannot construct data type datetime, some of the arguments have values which are not valid.`

My SQL uses `DATETIMEFROMPARTS`, but it's fine evaluating that function in the select - it's only a problem when I filter on the selected value.

It's also demonstrating weird, can't-possibly-be-happening behaviour w.r.t. other changes to the query.

My query looks roughly like this:

```
WITH FilteredDataWithDate (
    SELECT *, DATETIMEFROMPARTS(...some integer columns representing date data...) AS Date
    FROM Table
    WHERE <unrelated pre-condition filter>
)
SELECT * FROM FilteredDataWithDate
  WHERE Date > '2020-01-01'
```

If I run that query, then it errors with the `invalid data` error.
But if I omit the final `Date >` filter, then it happily renders every result record, so clearly none of the values it's filtering on are invalid.

I've also manually examined the contents of `Table WHERE <unrelated pre-condition filter>` and verified that everything is a valid date.

It also has a wild collection of other behaviours:

- If I replace all of `...some integer columns representing date data...` with hard-coded numbers then it's fine.
- If I replace *some* parts of that data with hardcoded values, that fixes it, but others don't. I don't find any particular patterns in what does or doesn't help.
- If I remove most of the `*` columns from the `Table` select. Then it starts to be fine again.

  - Specifically, it appears to break any time I include an `nvarchar(max)` column in the CTE.
- If I add an additional filter to the CTE that limits the results to Id values in the following ranges, then the results are:

  - 130,000 and 140,000. Error.
  - 130,000 and 135,000. Fine.
  - 135,000 and 140,000. Fine.!!!!
- Filtering by the `Date` column breaks everything ... but `ORDER BY Date` is fine. *(and confirms that all dates lie within perfectly sensible bounds.)*
- Adding `TOP 1000000` makes it work ... even though there are only about 1000 rows.

... WTAF?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took me a while to decode, but it turns out that the SS compiler doesn't necessarily restrict its execution of the function just to rows that are, or could be, relevant to the result set.

Depending on the execution plan it arrives at, the function could get called on *any* record in `Table`, even one that doesn't satisfy `WHERE <unrelated pre-condition filter>`.

This was found by another user, for another function, [over here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/datefromparts-and-convert-failing-but-only-when-inside-an-sp/page/2#post-3724373).

So the fact that it could return all the results without the filter wasn't actually proving that every input into the function was valid. And indeed there were some records in the table that weren't in the result set, but still had invalid data.

That actually means that even if you were to add an explicit `WHERE` filter to exclude rows containing invalid date-component data ... that isn't actually guaranteed to fix it, because the function may *still* get called against the 'excluded' rows.

Each of the random other things I did will have been influencing the query plan in one way or another that happened to fix/break things.

The solution is, naturally, to fix the underlying table data.

Comment: Yeah, this is a really sucky SQL Server bug that will likely never gets fixed. Another way to avoid the problem is that use CASE WHEN to make sure your function isn't called at all, unless all fields are correct

Comment: You can try `OPTION( FORCE ORDER )`  hint. This may solve your issue at the possible cost of performance.

Comment: UPDATED: @siggemannen, this is not a bug but a feature. As SQL Server chooses a plan for how to execute a query there is no guarantee that the order of evaluation of `WHERE` filters and `SELECT` functions will be maintained as long as theoretically they return the same result e.g. 2 + 3 + 4 = 4 + 2 + 3. (See Warning in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement). This behavior was introduced in SQL 2005. Plain CTEs do not have any functional effect on the query. They are just syntax sugar.

Comment: Yeah, i guess, although the problem is that some orders of evaluation lead to no result at all, which in my opinion should lead to SQL Server rejecting them outright perhaps. But yeah, it is what it is and will probably not change